Woocommerce mirrors cart and checkout page
I am having some troubles with WooCommerce and WordPress.
The Cart Page and Checkout Page set in the WooCommerce Setting under "Advanced" mirrors each other. If I do a change to the cart page, it mirrors over to the checkout page too, and also if I do it the other way.
I've tried deleting the pages, and re-creating them using the built in "Create Default WooCommerce Pages", but then I just get both looking like checkout pages. I checked the shortcode and its the same on both [woocommerce_checkout].
Has anyone seen this before, or have a solution for this?

Problem solved! I found the solution and what was causing the problem. The site I am just managing, was built by a former "web designer", and he had activated some global layouts in the Divi Page Builder, on all the standard woo pages (my account, checkout, cart, terms). The global layouts caused the mirroring on those pages, when the pages where selected in the Advanced-tab in the Settings-panel. So all those pages appeared as the same, only under different page names.
To troubleshoot I deactivated plugin after plugin, and then I tried to replace the theme with another theme. The theme replace worked, so I started looking into the theme's own settings, and all other settings on the Page Builder tab. Then I deactivated all the layouts, one by one until I found out it was one of those which was causing it. I've never used Divi Builder or any of those additional page builders, so its safe to say I learned something during this troubleshooting.

Just replace The shortcode for the cart page with [woocommerce_cart]

Thank you for trying to help me. I have tried thats option already, but with no luck sadly. I have tried troubleshooting with deactivating plugins and changing themes too. The theme I am using is the "Divi"-theme, with the "Divi"-builder. I think this is whats causing the trouble, but can't find out why.

What do you get on the cart page when applying the shortcode?

I found a solution now. I wasnt the one who built the site, and the former designer had used Divi Page Builder global layouts which caused the problem. If I saved the the shortcode for the woo cart on the cart page, it mirrors over to the checkout page. If I do the same on the checkout page, only with the checkout shortcode, it mirrors over to the cart page.
